# Laravel 5.2 - user is logged in only after successfull login redirect, once I do action user is not more logged in

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5.2 and [Laravel Authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) out of the box.
Here is my steps:
1) installing laravel
2) php artisan migrate
3) php artisan make:auth

Everything is ready, at least it should be...

Than I open localhost/project/public

a) Press on Register link, registering new account, if successful it redirects to /home and tell that I am logged in and shows my username. b) But once I am clicked to another link (e.g. Home button which redirects to /), than user is no more logged in. And because I am not logged in I am able to see Login and Register links, but they are redirected to /home as it expected.

And I mentioned that if I comment this line in AuthController (to allow access to login page even if I am logged in)

```
public function __construct()
{
    //$this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}
```

after step b) with this commented line I press Login or Register link and... user is logged in again.. Very strange behavior.
Same behavior if I open http://localhost/project/public/home, it says that I am logged in.

Generated code from routes.php file:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
Route::auth();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index'); });
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Check [this link out](http://test.heroesplay.com/) and tell me if this does the same thing. If not, I will tell you what I changed.

Comment: Seems it's working there.., but it's not the same behavior for me.. it's your website? could you please add this to do final check? Add this to routes.php: Route::get('/test', function () {
 if (Auth::check()) {
  echo 'Logged in';
 } else {
  echo 'Not logged in';
 }
});

Comment: @DerekPollard, you can tell me what you have changed.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So essentially, this is what my routes.php file looks like and it works perfectly:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Routes File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you will register all of the routes in an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/



/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This route group applies the "web" middleware group to every route
| it contains. The "web" middleware group is defined in your HTTP
| kernel and includes session state, CSRF protection, and more.
|
*/

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    //
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
    Route::auth();

    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });

    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
});
```

Comment: it's really working.. Then now I should put all my future routes inside middleware 'web' to make this this work correctly? It's such strange behaviour. Could you please explain how it's work?

Comment: I have been trying to figure out exactly the reasoning behind this as well. I have been using Laravel for quiet some time and 5.2 seems to have the oddest behaviour when it comes to routing.

Comment: I wanted to put this answer as best answer, but I have checked 2 more things :( when do login and enter wrong pass it redirect to public/login and page is blank, same when send restore password. But when I make mistakes in registration, everything is fine, it shows errors on same page...

Comment: I did sudo chmod -R guo+w boostrap and I did sudo chmod -R guo+w storage and it's WORKS!!! Thank you very much!! Have a nice day!

Comment: YAY! Glad I could be of assistance to you!

Comment: Yes, all functionality, even restore password (email and change password) :) I am very happy